# nodejs how to read indexeddb

Tags: node.js, indexeddb

Are there nodejs libraries for working with indexeddb? I haven’t found any of them that are normal so that you can open the database by passing the path to the file there. I really searched on Github but didn't find anything normal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this package has what you are looking for, https://www.npmjs.com/package/fake-indexeddb

Comment: import "fake-indexeddb/auto";

var request = indexedDB.open("C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\IndexedDB\\chrome-extension_someext_0.indexeddb.leveldb", 3);
request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    const db = request.result;

    console.log(db.objectStoreNames);
};

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But nothing worked out for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).